# Store values in a file in the same

Tags: powershell, ssl

I have the following code that extracts features of ssl certificates and stores them in a file ,but he writes each value in a line , I want to know how to make sure that within an iteration of my loop, the three values are written on the same line 
To make my self clear this is the output that i have now

> CN=localhost
>
> BD94E0B92BEFFA0A09B2FB6EC302CE27792A7181
>
> 4/10/2022 1:00:00 AM
>
> CN=Microsoft Remote Attestation Service
>
> 9ED7510E0D1073B6CEEE72B4C9A614E9F79E921F
>
> 3/10/2018 9:34:47 AM
>
> CN="Snaiso, aba@snaiso.com", C=DE
>
> 5AB0ED72FE73F300A17A2434BB9E9FEE2E9AEB16
>
> 10/14/2006 8:50:20 AM

what I want to have is

> CN=localhost
>    BD94E0B92BEFFA0A09B2FB6EC302CE27792A7181
>    4/10/2022 1:00:00 AM
>   CN="Snaiso, aba@snaiso.com", C=DE
>   5AB0ED72FE73F300A17A2434BB9E9FEE2E9AEB16
>   10/14/2006 8:50:20 AM

Below is the code that I wrote

```
`   
$route = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\"
$count = (Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My\*).Count
$count=$count-1

For ($i=0; $i -le $count; $i++)
{ 
$subject = (Get-ChildItem $route)[$i].Subject
$thumb = (Get-ChildItem $route)[$i].Thumbprint
$expiredate = (Get-ChildItem $route)[$i].NotAfter
$startDate = Get-Date
$diff = (New-TimeSpan -Start $startDate -End $expiredate)
Add-Content -Path C:\Users\hmk\Desktop\file.txt -Value 
$subject,$thumb,$expiredate
}`
```

Comment: What is the context of and ultimate purpose of this? There might be better fitting single-line options for structuring your data (like a csv) than simply concatening the values on a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the strings in double quotes:

```
Add-Content -Path C:\Users\hmk\Desktop\file.txt -Value "$subject,$thumb,$expiredate"
```

If you have a variable number of items to store .net string would handle that

```
Add-Content -Path C:\Users\hmk\Desktop\file.txt -Value [string]::join(',' , @( $subject,$thumb,$expiredate) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-Join` operator for this:

```
$subject,$thumb,$expiredate -Join " "
```

See [About Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-6)